# how can I run custom extension files in python script?

Tags: python

I have a file with extension (.logs) which has the data without xml format. I also have a tool say abc.exe (added to PATH) which takes the .logs file as input and generates a new file with properly formatted XML. So, I'm trying to run the same tool using python, MY.py is reading the input file rather running it using abc.exe. How can I make the file run using abc.exe using pythons scripting?

Comment: You need to provide some source code for this to be answerable.

Comment: Do you want to launch `abc.exe` with proper parameters via python script, or reimplement entire `abc.exe` functionality in python?

Comment: I want to launch abc.exe via python script.                                                import subprocess
callgenLogs = '"D:\\WFM\\32001\\store_(3)\\store_2014_06_12__02_14_06.logs"'
subprocess.call(callgenLogs)--> here the above logs file when I double click will automatically generates the output. but when running through python, its reading the conent of the file

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(['exefile', 'cmdlinearg1', 'cmdlinearg2'])`

Comment: @user2531608 Edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lunch your program (let's say, abc.exe), just use this code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["abc.exe", "arg1","arg2"])
```